# How do I display the second and third most recent posts from a category in WordPress

Tags: wordpress

I am displaying previews of the three most recent news articles on my homepage. The most recent post will be displayed in a different format to the second and third most recent posts.
I am currently displaying all three the same with the following code

```
<?php query_posts('cat=2 && showposts=3'); 
                    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
                            <div class="column">
                                <div class="news-article">
                                    <p class="news-date"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive img-rounded news-img' )); } ?>
                                        <p class="news-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                                    </a>
                                    <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                                        <p class="pull-right">Read more...</p>
                                    </a>
                                    <span class="clearfix"></span>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                    ?>
```

How can I add another loop which will separate the second and third most recent posts from the most recent post?
I did not want to use postID as the posts will change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested but you could try:

```
    <?php 
    $count = 0;
    query_posts('cat=2 && showposts=3'); 
    if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); 
    if($count == 0)
    {
    ?>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
            <div class="column">
                <div class="news-article">
                    <p class="news-date"><?php the_time( get_option( 'date_format' ) ); ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail('full', array( 'class' => 'img-responsive img-rounded news-img' )); } ?>
                    <p class="news-headline"><?php the_title(); ?></p>
                     </a>
                     <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
                    <p class="pull-right">Read more...</p>
                    </a>
                    <span class="clearfix"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
    $count = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        //Some other layout here
    }
    endwhile;
    endif;
    ?>
```

The above will check if `$count` is `0` and if it is, then do the layout and the count will then equal to `1`. So the next time around `$count` won't be 0, so it will run what is in the `else` (which will be your layout).

Comment: Thank you @Howlin, this was very helpful. I only made two very minor changes for it to work, which were remove the semi-colon in line 5, and close and open php at //Some other layout here

Answer (score 2):

The two arguments in the WP_Query function below combine to retrieve the second most recent post, then the HTML below displays that post.

```
<div class="video-message">
  <p>
  <ul>
  <!-- // Define our WP Query Parameters -->
  <?php 
  $the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1,'offset' => 1 ) ); 
  ?>

  <!-- // Start our WP Query -->
  <?php while ($the_query -> have_posts()) : $the_query -> the_post(); ?>

  <!-- // Display the Post Title with Hyperlink -->
  <p><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></p>

  <?php 
  endwhile;
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
  </ul>
  </p>
 </div> 

</div>
```

To display the third most recent post would require changing the offset value to 2, so that the program skips over the two most recent posts.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query( array( 'posts_per_page' => 1,'offset' => 2 ) );
```

This method is discussed in the [Pagination Parameters section](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#post-type-parameters) of the WordPress Code Reference.

Answer (score 0):

I use WP_Query like this to show all posts from the fourth most recent one:

```
<?php
    $query4 = new WP_Query( 'posts_per_page=4&offset=3' );
?>
```